# How to add a button in front of a GMSMapView

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, gmsmapview

I am trying to add a button in front of a `GMSMapView` view.
Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var testButton: UIButton! 
@IBOutlet weak var mapView2: GMSMapView! 
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadView()
}
```

then here is the `loadView()` method

```
override func loadView() {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 54.2785691, longitude: -8.4620978, zoom: 18.0)
    let mapView2 = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    view = mapView2 
    mapView2.bringSubviewToFront(testButton)
}
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: please add more context , where you create and add **testButton** , post all relevant code

Comment: @Sh_Khan Is that enough context? Im new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
class MyVc:UIViewController { 
  @IBOutlet weak var testButton: UIButton! 
  @IBOutlet weak var mapView2: GMSMapView! 
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 54.2785691, longitude: -8.4620978, zoom: 18.0)
    mapView2.animate(to: camera)
    view.bringSubviewToFront(testButton)
  }
}
```

I expect UI in IB

```
View-> 
    -testButton
    -mapView2
```

Btw instead of `bringSubviewToFront` you can re-arrange the views to

```
View-> 
    -mapView2
    -testButton
```

Where bottom element is at the front

Also don't implement `loadView` for such issue as it only matters when you create the vc programmatically or want to add some item in addition to IB and in latter case you should call `super.loadView()`